# class not found exception intellij -- source folder is set correctly

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Intellij is not able to run the Main class as it throws class not found exception.
My source directory is set correctly, its a maven project so the main class is also defined in POM. I also have set the path for Project compiler output, although no class are there in this path.
and i am using "Inherit project compile output path".
what i have found out is that the class files are not creating in the Project compiler output folder, but i am not sure why is that not working.

Comment: Post your POM, stackstrace.

Comment: Also, check file > Project Structure > Modules to verify that your content root settings are indeed recognized as expected and are actually marked as 'sources' root.

Answer (score 0):

You could try clearing the cache for the IDE and restarting. Select - File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart